# How to unify many controls in word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I'm creating a table with many identical combo boxes in word 2013. I don't want them to be separately editable.

In something like WPF I would create a comboBox1 in the code and then bind it to many places in the table. How do i replicate this behavior with word 2013 controls? I'm happy of copy and paste the control to where it's needed, but I need it to remain the same centrally edited control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is control controls that are linked to Custom XML. The orange controls are linked to document properties and work on the same basis .

If you want a quick solution you can actually just use one of the document property based content controls to achieve what you are looking for. Change the name of the content control by going to the Developer Tab, enabling Design Mode and changing the name under properties. The content is stored in the document property and you will see the linked behavior still remains intact when you modify one of the controls.

Otherwise you will need to setup your own custom XML property. This is not so easy, however one of the Microsoft MVP created a [great program](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/cc_var_bm_doc_prop_tools_addin.html) to help with that.